# eager loading eloquent for relationship tables

Tags: php, laravel, eager-loading

how to load eloquent egar loading for below table.

I want to get `paul->donation[{eldery,material->clothes}, {orphan,material->aircon}]`
How can I get it by laravel eloquent eager loading ?

Below is the database structure and content

```
Members
+----+-------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Paul              |
|  2 | John              |
|  3 | kathy             |
|  4 | Mary              |
+----+-------------------+

donation
+----+-------------------+
| id | name              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | eldery care       |
|  2 | orphan school     |
+----+-------------------+


donation_member pivot
+----+-----------+-----------+
| id | member_id | donate_id |
+----+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |         1 |         1 |
|  2 |         2 |         1 |
|  3 |         4 |         1 |
|  4 |         1 |         2 |
|  5 |         3 |         2 |
|  6 |         4 |         2 |
+----+-----------+-----------+

Required Material
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | name          | donation_id    |   priority   | is_donated   |
+----+---------------+----------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | medicine      |       1        |       1      |     1        | 
|  2 | clothes       |       1        |       2      |     0        | 
|  3 | aircondition  |       2        |       1      |     0        |
|  4 | Desktop       |       2        |       2      |     0        | 
+----+--------------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Don't you know how to set up models / relationships? The eager loading concept is nicely documented: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: @Quasdunk, I wish to get eloquent like, `$members = Member:with('donation', 'material')->where('material.is_donated', false)->where('priority', youngest)->get();`

Comment: my problem is hasManyThrough doesn't work for `member to material through donation.` beacuse donation table doesn't have material_id as foreign key. So how can I get showed query. `$members = Member:with('donation', 'material')->where('material.is_donated', false)->where('priority', youngest)->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading nested relationsships ist just as easy as flat ones, and you can also add constraints:

```
// Not sure what you're trying to do with the priority, I guess
// you just want the highest one?
$highestPriority = 3;

$members = Members::with([

    'donations',

    'donations.material' => function($query) use ($highestPriority) {
        $query->where('is_dontated', false);
        $query->where('priority', $highestPriority);
    }

])->get();
```

**But:** These constraints only apply to the relationship subset, not to the whole colletion. That means, if you want to just get all members and donations with the highest priority material, you would either have to

- work with the fetched collection (which is of type [Illuminate\Support\Collection](http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)), maybe something like `$members->filter(...)`,
- work with Joins, or
- approach it from the inverse relationship (`Material::where(['is_donated' => true, 'priority' => $highest)])->with(['donations', 'donations.member'])->get()`;

Comment: thank for your help, I am still stuck in same error `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'donations.material_id' in 'on clause'. `I am looking for a way to access material through donation. because materials has donation_id but not material_id in donation table. :-(

Comment: `$donation = donation::with(['materials' => function($query){
          $query->groupBy('donation_id');
       $query->where('is_donated',false);
     }])->get();`  
I got this for donation-> material query 
but I can't use Member Model to access material.

Comment: Quasdunk, It work like a charm. Working great but just a bit modification. But I approve, your nested relationships work great.  `donations.materials -> function ($query){...}` work out.
Thank bro.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to understand is to use lazy eager loading. I prefer to use it also. First get the collection of objects or object and then load relationships.

```
$members = Member::where('material.is_donated', false)->where('priority', youngest)->get();
$members->load("donation");
$members->load("material");
```

For this you need to have Eloquent relationship methods donation() and material() defined in class Member.

Comment: smartman, thank for your answer, may I know one things how to make relationship between member and material. because there is no dierct relation between these two tables but just through donation table.